# Bookmarks not linking with Table of Figures and Bibliography properly

Tags: pdf, bookmarks

I've been trying to get the `bookmark` package to work with my thesis, and for the most part I'm happy with the results; however, I'm having some problems with the links for the Table of Figures and Bibliography.  Below is a rather extensive MWE of my code for the various sections and chapters etc.  I've included all the packages I'm using in my thesis (thus far) in case there's anything that might be causing some conflicts.

Having compiled the TeX file and opened the pdf all the various bookmarks are present, however when I click on the bookmark for Table of Figures it takes me to the Contents page.  Similarly, when I click on the bookmark for the bibliography it takes me to 6.1.1, the subsection in Chapter 6.

Can anyone shed any light on what's going wrong here?

Many thanks!

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[round,colon]{natbib}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,threeparttable}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\bookmarksetup{bold=false}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{Knu86,
    author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
    year = {1986},
    title = {The \TeX book},
  }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\vspace*{1in}
{\LARGE Quantifying rates of landscape evolution in carbonate terrains using U-Pb dating of speleothems}
\par
\vspace{1.5in}
{\large Christopher James Martin Smith}
\par
\vfill
A dissertation submitted to the University of Bristol in accordance with the requirements for award of the degree of Doctor of Philosophy in the Faculty of Science.
\par
\vspace{0.5in}
School of Geographical Sciences
\par
\vspace{0.5in}
University of Bristol
\par
\vspace{0.5in}
September 2014
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\chapter*{Declaration}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Declaration}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgements}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter*{Abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\lipsum[1]

\label{Table of Contents}
\cleardoublepage
\pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{Contents}
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\label{List of Figures}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures
\newpage

\label{Lits of Tables}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
\listoftables
\newpage

\label{Nomenclature}
\printnomenclature
\newpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[1]\citep{Knu86}
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Literature Review}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Methodology}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Results}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Discussion}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Conclusion}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[1]

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography} 
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The bookmark links to the anchor that `\addcontentsline` uses. Since it comes *before* the table of figures or the bibliography, it links to some event before (the table of contents/the last subsection). `\phantomsection` can be used to create a new anchor:

```
\cleardoublepage
\pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{Contents}
\label{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\phantomsection
\label{List of Figures}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures
\newpage

\phantomsection
\label{List of Tables}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
\listoftables
\newpage
...

\clearpage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography} 
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}
```

### Alternative for the standard lists

`\addcontentsline` should go to the very first beginning of the lists. `\addtocontents` allows such placement:

```
In the preamble (or right after `\begin{document}`:

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\label{Table of Contents}}%
  \addtocontents{lof}{%
    \protect\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\listfigurename}%
    \protect\label{List of Figures}%
  }%
  \addtocontents{lot}{%
    \protect\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\listtablename}%
    \protect\label{List of Tables}%
  }%
}
```

Then `\addcontentsline` and `\label` refer to the chapter title of the list.
And the code in the document simplifies to

```
\cleardoublepage
\pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{Contents}
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\listoffigures
\newpage

\listoftables
\newpage
```

Disadvantage: It takes some runs, because in the first run `\addcontentsline` goes into the `.toc` file, in the second run, it goes on to the `.lof` or `.lot` file and in the third run the entry is set in the list of figures/tables.

Comment: That's brilliant.  Thank you very much.  If I were to add a section for a nomenclature, would I need to add a `\phantomsection` for that as well?

Comment: @cjms85: Yes, `\addcontentsline` should go to the first page of the nomenclature. Therefore it goes before `\nomenclature`. Then `\addcontentsline` needs an anchor that is set by `\phantomsection`.