# List of Tables caption entry problems with Bookmarks package

Tags: table-of-contents, captions, bookmarks

Since implementing the `bookmark` package and resolving the issues with [Bookmarks not linking with Table of Figures and Bibliography properly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161518/bookmarks-not-linking-with-table-of-figures-and-bibliography-properly), I've noticed that the `bookmark` package is causing long entries in the List of Tables to appear on one line, meaning that they run off the page, rather than continuing on to the next line as they normally would.  Below are two examples of the same code, one with the `bookmark` package and mark up running and the other with them commented out.

How can I stop my long table caption from running off the page?  is there something in the code below that's associated with the `bookmark` package that's causing it to do this?

**Bookmarks enabled - long entries in LoT appear on a single line and run off the page**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[round,colon]{natbib}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,threeparttable}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\bookmarksetup{bold=false}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{Knu86,
    author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
    year = {1986},
    title = {The \TeX book},
  }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\vspace*{1in}
{\LARGE Quantifying rates of landscape evolution in carbonate terrains using U-Pb dating of speleothems}
\par
\vspace{1.5in}
{\large Christopher James Martin Smith}
\par
\vfill
A dissertation submitted to the University of Bristol in accordance with the requirements for award of the degree of Doctor of Philosophy in the Faculty of Science.
\par
\vspace{0.5in}
School of Geographical Sciences
\par
\vspace{0.5in}
University of Bristol
\par
\vspace{0.5in}
September 2014
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\phantomsection
\chapter*{Declaration}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Declaration}
\lipsum[1]

\phantomsection
\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgements}
\lipsum[1]

\phantomsection
\chapter*{Abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\lipsum[1]

\cleardoublepage
\pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{Contents}
\label{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\phantomsection
\label{List of Figures}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures
\newpage

\phantomsection
\label{List of Tables}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
\listoftables
\newpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[1]\citep{Knu86}
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Literature Review}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption[Alpha emitting radioactive decay series.]{Alpha emitting radioactive decay series.}
\label{tab:alpha decay series}
\begin{threeparttable}
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{l c c c c c c}
\toprule
            &             &                &                            &                & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Number of decays} \\
Series type & Series name & Parent nucleus & Half-life (\num{e9} years) & Stable nucleus & 
\makebox[1.5cm]{$\alpha$} &
\makebox[1.5cm]{$\beta^{-}$} \\
\midrule
$A = 4n$    & Thorium           & \ch{^{232}Th} & 14.05     & \ch{^{208}Pb}     & 6 & 4 \\
$A = 4n+1$  & Neptunium         & \ch{^{237}Np} & 0.0021    & \ch{^{205}Tl}     & 8 & 5 \\
$A = 4n+2$  & Radium (Uranium)  & \ch{^{238}U}  & 4.4683    & \ch{^{206}Pb}     & 8 & 6 \\
$A = 4n+3$  & Actinium          & \ch{^{235}U}  & 0.7038    & \ch{^{207}Pb}     & 7 & 4 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Methodology}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption[Decay modes and half-lives for all nuclides in the radium (uranium) and actinium series decay chains.]{Decay modes and half-lives for all nuclides in the radium (uranium) and actinium series decay chains.  Half-lives are from (1) \citep{Knu86}.}
\label{tab:238U and 235U decay chains}
\begin{threeparttable}
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{*{10}{c}}
\toprule
\ch{^{238}U} decay chain &  &  &  &  & \ch{^{235}U} decay chain &  &  &  &  \\
Isotope & Decay mode & Half-life & $t$ & Ref & Isotope & Decay mode & Half-life & $t$ & Ref \\
\midrule
\ch{^{238}U}    & $\alpha$          & $4.4683\pm 0.0048$    & Ga    & 1 &\ch{^{235}U}   & $\alpha$          & $0.70381\pm 0.00096$ & Ga & 1 \\
\ch{^{234}Th}   & $\beta^-$         & $24.1$                & days  & 2 &\ch{^{231}Th}  & $\beta^-$         & $1.063$ & days & 2 \\
\ch{^{234}Pa}, \ch{^{234m}Pa} & $\beta^-$           & $6.69, 1.159$             & hours, min    & 2, 3 &\ch{^{231}Pa}   & $\alpha$          & $32.760\pm 0.22$ & ka & 6 \\
\ch{^{234}U}    & $\alpha$          & $245.62\pm 0.26$      & ka    & 4 &\ch{^{227}Ac}  & $\alpha, \beta^-$ & $21.77\pm 0.02$ & a & 5 \\
\ch{^{230}Th}   & $\alpha$          & $75.584\pm 0.11$      & ka    & 4 &\ch{^{227}Th}  & $\alpha$          & $18.72$ & days & 2 \\
\ch{^{226}Ra}   & $\alpha$          & $1.599\pm 0.004$      & ka    & 5 &\ch{^{223}Fr}  & $\alpha, \beta^-$ & $22$ & min & 2 \\
\ch{^{222}Rn}   & $\alpha$          & $3.823\pm 0.004$      & days  & 5 &\ch{^{223}Ra}  & $\alpha$          & $11.435$ & days & 2 \\
\ch{^{218}Po}   & $\alpha, \beta^-$ & $3.04$                & min   & 2 &\ch{^{219}At}  & $\alpha, \beta^-$ & $50$ & s & 2 \\
\ch{^{218}At}   & $\alpha, \beta^-$ & $1.6$                 & s     & 2 &\ch{^{219}Rn}  & $\alpha$          & $3.96$ & s & 2 \\
\ch{^{218}Rn}   & $\alpha$          & $35$                  & ms    & 2 &\ch{^{215}Bi}  & $\beta^-$         & $7.7$ & min & 2 \\
\ch{^{214}Pb}   & $\beta^-$         & $26.9$                & min   & 2 &\ch{^{215}Po}  & $\alpha, \beta^-$ & $1.78$ & ms & 2 \\
\ch{^{214}Bi}   & $\alpha, \beta^-$ & $19.7$                & min   & 2 &\ch{^{215}At}  & $\alpha$          & $0.1$ & ms & 2 \\
\ch{^{214}Po}   & $\alpha$          & $0.1637$              & ms    & 2 &\ch{^{211}Pb}  & $\beta^-$         & $36.1$ & min & 2 \\
\ch{^{214}Tl}   & $\beta^-$         & $1.3$                 & min   & 2 &\ch{^{211}Bi}  & $\alpha, \beta^-$ & $2.14$ & min & 2 \\
\ch{^{210}Pb}   & $\alpha, \beta^-$ & $22.6\pm 0.1$         & a     & 5 &\ch{^{211}Po}  & $\alpha$          & $0.516$ & s & 2 \\
\ch{^{210}Bi}   & $\alpha, \beta^-$ & $5.01$                & days  & 2 &\ch{^{207}Tl}  & $\beta^-$         & $4.77$ & min & 2 \\
\ch{^{210}Po}   & $\alpha$          & $138.4\pm 0.1$        & days  & 5 &\ch{^{207}Pb}  &                   & stable &  &  \\
\ch{^{206}Hg}   & $\beta^-$         & $8.2$                 & min   & 2 &               &                   &  &  &  \\
\ch{^{206}Tl}   & $\beta^-$         & $4.2$                 & min   & 2 &               &                   &  &  &  \\
\ch{^{206}Pb}   &                   & stable                &       &   &               &                   &  &  &  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}


\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Results}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Discussion}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Conclusion}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[1]

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography} 
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

**Bookmarks commented out - long entries in LoT appear on multiple lines**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[round,colon]{natbib}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,threeparttable}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
%\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\bookmarksetup{bold=false}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{Knu86,
    author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
    year = {1986},
    title = {The \TeX book},
  }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\vspace*{1in}
{\LARGE Quantifying rates of landscape evolution in carbonate terrains using U-Pb dating of speleothems}
\par
\vspace{1.5in}
{\large Christopher James Martin Smith}
\par
\vfill
A dissertation submitted to the University of Bristol in accordance with the requirements for award of the degree of Doctor of Philosophy in the Faculty of Science.
\par
\vspace{0.5in}
School of Geographical Sciences
\par
\vspace{0.5in}
University of Bristol
\par
\vspace{0.5in}
September 2014
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\pagenumbering{roman}
%\phantomsection
\chapter*{Declaration}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Declaration}
\lipsum[1]

%\phantomsection
\chapter*{Acknowledgements}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgements}
\lipsum[1]

%\phantomsection
\chapter*{Abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\lipsum[1]

\cleardoublepage
%\pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{Contents}
\label{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents
\newpage

%\phantomsection
\label{List of Figures}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures
\newpage

%\phantomsection
\label{List of Tables}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
\listoftables
\newpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[1]\citep{Knu86}
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Literature Review}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption[Alpha emitting radioactive decay series.]{Alpha emitting radioactive decay series.}
\label{tab:alpha decay series}
\begin{threeparttable}
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{l c c c c c c}
\toprule
            &             &                &                            &                & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Number of decays} \\
Series type & Series name & Parent nucleus & Half-life (\num{e9} years) & Stable nucleus & 
\makebox[1.5cm]{$\alpha$} &
\makebox[1.5cm]{$\beta^{-}$} \\
\midrule
$A = 4n$    & Thorium           & \ch{^{232}Th} & 14.05     & \ch{^{208}Pb}     & 6 & 4 \\
$A = 4n+1$  & Neptunium         & \ch{^{237}Np} & 0.0021    & \ch{^{205}Tl}     & 8 & 5 \\
$A = 4n+2$  & Radium (Uranium)  & \ch{^{238}U}  & 4.4683    & \ch{^{206}Pb}     & 8 & 6 \\
$A = 4n+3$  & Actinium          & \ch{^{235}U}  & 0.7038    & \ch{^{207}Pb}     & 7 & 4 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Methodology}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption[Decay modes and half-lives for all nuclides in the radium (uranium) and actinium series decay chains.]{Decay modes and half-lives for all nuclides in the radium (uranium) and actinium series decay chains.  Half-lives are from (1) \citep{Knu86}.}
\label{tab:238U and 235U decay chains}
\begin{threeparttable}
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{*{10}{c}}
\toprule
\ch{^{238}U} decay chain &  &  &  &  & \ch{^{235}U} decay chain &  &  &  &  \\
Isotope & Decay mode & Half-life & $t$ & Ref & Isotope & Decay mode & Half-life & $t$ & Ref \\
\midrule
\ch{^{238}U}    & $\alpha$          & $4.4683\pm 0.0048$    & Ga    & 1 &\ch{^{235}U}   & $\alpha$          & $0.70381\pm 0.00096$ & Ga & 1 \\
\ch{^{234}Th}   & $\beta^-$         & $24.1$                & days  & 2 &\ch{^{231}Th}  & $\beta^-$         & $1.063$ & days & 2 \\
\ch{^{234}Pa}, \ch{^{234m}Pa} & $\beta^-$           & $6.69, 1.159$             & hours, min    & 2, 3 &\ch{^{231}Pa}   & $\alpha$          & $32.760\pm 0.22$ & ka & 6 \\
\ch{^{234}U}    & $\alpha$          & $245.62\pm 0.26$      & ka    & 4 &\ch{^{227}Ac}  & $\alpha, \beta^-$ & $21.77\pm 0.02$ & a & 5 \\
\ch{^{230}Th}   & $\alpha$          & $75.584\pm 0.11$      & ka    & 4 &\ch{^{227}Th}  & $\alpha$          & $18.72$ & days & 2 \\
\ch{^{226}Ra}   & $\alpha$          & $1.599\pm 0.004$      & ka    & 5 &\ch{^{223}Fr}  & $\alpha, \beta^-$ & $22$ & min & 2 \\
\ch{^{222}Rn}   & $\alpha$          & $3.823\pm 0.004$      & days  & 5 &\ch{^{223}Ra}  & $\alpha$          & $11.435$ & days & 2 \\
\ch{^{218}Po}   & $\alpha, \beta^-$ & $3.04$                & min   & 2 &\ch{^{219}At}  & $\alpha, \beta^-$ & $50$ & s & 2 \\
\ch{^{218}At}   & $\alpha, \beta^-$ & $1.6$                 & s     & 2 &\ch{^{219}Rn}  & $\alpha$          & $3.96$ & s & 2 \\
\ch{^{218}Rn}   & $\alpha$          & $35$                  & ms    & 2 &\ch{^{215}Bi}  & $\beta^-$         & $7.7$ & min & 2 \\
\ch{^{214}Pb}   & $\beta^-$         & $26.9$                & min   & 2 &\ch{^{215}Po}  & $\alpha, \beta^-$ & $1.78$ & ms & 2 \\
\ch{^{214}Bi}   & $\alpha, \beta^-$ & $19.7$                & min   & 2 &\ch{^{215}At}  & $\alpha$          & $0.1$ & ms & 2 \\
\ch{^{214}Po}   & $\alpha$          & $0.1637$              & ms    & 2 &\ch{^{211}Pb}  & $\beta^-$         & $36.1$ & min & 2 \\
\ch{^{214}Tl}   & $\beta^-$         & $1.3$                 & min   & 2 &\ch{^{211}Bi}  & $\alpha, \beta^-$ & $2.14$ & min & 2 \\
\ch{^{210}Pb}   & $\alpha, \beta^-$ & $22.6\pm 0.1$         & a     & 5 &\ch{^{211}Po}  & $\alpha$          & $0.516$ & s & 2 \\
\ch{^{210}Bi}   & $\alpha, \beta^-$ & $5.01$                & days  & 2 &\ch{^{207}Tl}  & $\beta^-$         & $4.77$ & min & 2 \\
\ch{^{210}Po}   & $\alpha$          & $138.4\pm 0.1$        & days  & 5 &\ch{^{207}Pb}  &                   & stable &  &  \\
\ch{^{206}Hg}   & $\beta^-$         & $8.2$                 & min   & 2 &               &                   &  &  &  \\
\ch{^{206}Tl}   & $\beta^-$         & $4.2$                 & min   & 2 &               &                   &  &  &  \\
\ch{^{206}Pb}   &                   & stable                &       &   &               &                   &  &  &  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}


\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Results}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Discussion}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Conclusion}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Subsection}
\lipsum[1]

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography} 
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Package `bookmark` loads package `hyperref` (for the anchors). Some drivers are not capable of generating links that are broken across lines, see section "Wrapped/broken link support" in `hyperref`'s [README](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/README.pdf)

Comment: I've had a look at the readme file for `hyperref` under section 7 and it suggests that a workaround to my problem is to use the `linktocpage` option, but it doesn't suggest how or where I implement this.  I've tried adding this to the command `\usepackage[linktocpage]{bookmark}`, but that didn't seem to do anything.  Similarly, when I added it to `\listoffigures[linktocpage]` it still didn't solve the problem.  And when I tried to load `hyperref` as a separate package, like so `\usepackage[linktocpage]{hyperref}` that just caused LaTeX to stop compiling.  Can you explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @cjms85: `\usepackage[linktocpage]{hyperref}\usepackage{bookmark}` or `\PassOptionsToPackage{linktocpage}{hyperref}\usepackage{bookmark}`.

Comment: Thank you.  I've just gone for the first option `\usepackage[linktocpage]{hyperref}\usepackage{bookmark}`.  Just out of interest, I had tried loading the `\usepackage[linktocpage]{hyperref}` earlier, on the line below `\usepackage{bookmark}` and that didn't seem to work.  I take it they have to be loaded on the same line?  Why is that?