# Wrong PDF bookmark for Bibliography chapter

Tags: bookmarks

I cannot set up correct PDF bookmark for Bibliography chapter in the backmatter.

The page number in TOC is correct, however the PDF bookmark consistently points to the last section in the mainmatter.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}
\pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{Contents}
\tableofcontents\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\begin{mainmatter}
    \chapter{Chapter A}
    \section{Section a}
\end{mainmatter}

\begin{backmatter}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
    \begin{thebibliography}{9}
    \end{thebibliography}
\end{backmatter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Change the order of `\addcontentsline` and \begin{thebibliography}`

Comment: And it is sufficient to write `\mainmatter` and `\backmatter`, not `\begin{mainmatter}` etc. Those constructs are true commands and not environments

Comment: Changing the order of \addcontentsline and \begin{thebibliography} produces good PDF bookmark but wrong page number in TOC (last page of Bibliography).

Comment: I used portions of your MWE and added another solution, however with `\printbibliography` instead of `\begin{thebibliography}`. At least in that short file the bookmarks and page numbers are correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Package [`tocbibind`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocbibind) can be used to include the chapter titles of the table of contents and the bibliography to the table of contents and the bookmarks:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{Chapter A}
\section{Section a}

\backmatter
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

**Remarks:**

- `\mainmatter`, `\backmatter` are commands rather than environments in class `book`.

Comment: @Robert: That are different questions, e.g. see this [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/161520/16967). Also there are counter `tocdepth` and option `depth` of package `bookmark` (= option `bookmarkdepth` of `hyperref`).

Answer (score 2):

There is already a good answer by Heiko Oberdiek, I just wanted to react on the comment by the OP about the wrong page number. However, I use the `biblatex` package.

```
\documentclass{book}%

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{bookmark}

% Normally biblio.bib is available on every TeXLive System in 
% the sub-directory bibtex/msc
\bibliography{biblio} 

\begin{document}
\pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{Contents}
\tableofcontents\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\mainmatter
    \chapter{Chapter A}
    \cite{Lam94} % Cite Leslie Lamport
    \section{Section a}

\backmatter
    \phantomsection
    \printbibliography%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}%  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can just pass `[heading=bibintoc]` to `\printbibliography`. See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/67155

Comment: @Rufflewind: Yes. I posted this answer more than 3 years ago, when my knowledge of biblatex was limited. Forgot about this answer. Thanks